# Macro to copy and/or move selected sheets to a new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone please help me with a macro? I want to move and/or copy a few selected sheets (hidden & visible) to a new workbook, but since I have a few workbooks open at a time, I want to be able to select worksheets in all open workbooks from like a drop down menu and move and/or copy to a new workbook. I want to move some and copy some worksheets so will need both options in selection box.

Please help as I have cracked my head on it and got nowhere.

I have tried the below:

```
Sub CopySheet()
    Dim i As Integer, x As Integer
    Dim shtname As String

        'i = Application.InputBox("Copy how many times?", "Copy sheet", Type:=1)
        'For x = 0 To i - 1
            ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            shtname = InputBox("What's the new sheet name?", "Sheet name?")
            ActiveSheet.Name = shtname
        'Next x

End Sub
```

But this will mean I have to type every sheet name every time.

Adam: While I try to run your code, it gives me an error - `variable not specified in row Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()`

How do I overcome it?

I still can't get it right Adam. I am very new to Macros and I may be doing something wrong with interpreting your instructions. Can you please suggest something like all included in one and run?

Where exactly in the original codes do I need to paste this code

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure you have added the checkbox for copying, and this checkbox is named "chkCopy". Make sure the "Name" property is "chkCopy", and not the caption. If you type "Me", the name for the checkbox should come up in the resulting list of code-completion suggestions.

Comment: Private Sub btnSubmit_Click() -> You need a button named btnSubmit in your worksheet to have @Adam's code working...

Answer (score 4):

This code should get you going. It is all of the code-behind for a UserForm with two listboxes, a checkbox, and a command button for submit. The dropdowns are populated automatically depending on what workbooks are open and what worksheets these workbooks contain. It also has the option to move or copy the selected worksheet. However, you still will need to add the functionality for copying the sheet multiple times, but that will just be a loop, and shouldn't be too difficult.

```
'All of this code goes in the section which appears when you right click
'the form and select "View Code"
Option Explicit

Public Sub OpenWorksheetSelect()

    Dim WorksheetSelector As New frmWorksheetSelect
    WorksheetSelector.Show

End Sub

Private Sub lstWorkbooks_Change()

    FillWorksheetList

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    FillWorkbookList

End Sub


Sub FillWorkbookList()
'Add each workbook to the drop down

    Dim CurrentWorkbook As Workbook

    For Each CurrentWorkbook In Workbooks

        lstWorkbooks.AddItem CurrentWorkbook.Name

    Next CurrentWorkbook

End Sub

Sub FillWorksheetList()

    Dim WorkbookName As String

    WorkbookName = lstWorkbooks.Text

    If Len(WorkbookName) > 0 Then

        Dim CurrentWorksheet As Worksheet

        For Each CurrentWorksheet In Workbooks(WorkbookName).Sheets

            lstWorksheets.AddItem CurrentWorksheet.Name

        Next CurrentWorksheet

    End If

End Sub


Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()

    Dim WorkbookName As String, WorksheetName As String

    WorkbookName = lstWorkbooks.Text
    WorksheetName = lstWorksheets.Text

    If Len(WorkbookName) > 0 And Len(WorksheetName) > 0 Then

        If chkCopy = True Then
            Workbooks(WorkbookName).Sheets(WorksheetName).Copy    Before:=Workbooks.Add.Sheets(1)
        Else
            Workbooks(WorkbookName).Sheets(WorksheetName).Move Before:=Workbooks.Add.Sheets(1)
        End If

    End If

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: Upvoted this post to enable you editing your own post, in case you didn't have enough points to do it...